# How to fix invalid SSL record content type

Tags: java, security, networking, ssl

hello i am getting this error when trying to connect to SSL in java using the SSLFactory

Stack trace:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: invalid SSL record content type
at com.ibm.j9.jsse.SSLSocketImpl.completeHandshake(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.j9.jsse.SSLSocketImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
```

Here's the code error during handshake:

```
_socket = SocketFactory.getSslSocket( _socket, //Socket created before this call
                                       _address, //host that supports SSL
                                       _port.intValue() );

 SSLSocket tempSocket = (SSLSocket)_socket;

 String[] supportedCipherSuites = tempSocket.getSupportedCipherSuites();

 System.out.println( "Supported Cipher Suites:" );
 for( int i = 0; i < supportedCipherSuites.length; i++ )
 {
    System.out.println( supportedCipherSuites[i] );
 }     

 tempSocket.setUseClientMode( true );
 tempSocket.startHandshake();
```

Comment: and a trace of what data is being received from the server. Also any non-sensitive parts of the certificate that is in use.

Comment: the suite prints this:
Supported Cipher Suites:
SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

Comment: Where does `SocketFactory.getSslSocket(...)` come from? What's the full name of this `SocketFactory`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getSupportedCipherSuites()` only shows you which ciphers your local SSL implementation can support (regardless of whether they are enabled or not); It does not use the remote connection. So your "debug" output is always going to succeed with the same results, regardless of the target of your `SSLSocket`. The remote connection is not opened until you attempt to handshake (or if a handshake is forced by attempting to read or write to the stream, or access SSL session information).

Are you confident the outbound TCP connection you are making is to an SSL server? Have you been able to confirm this with a different client, such as a browser or the OpenSSL command line client?

Comment: Yes, the smtp server was configured to use SSL/TLS only
i also tried using OpenSSL command and confirmed that the server im using is using ssl.

**SSL handshake has read 2687 bytes and written 305 bytes**

do i have to worry about the Certificate before handshake happens?

Comment: There's your answer: smtp.gmail.com:587 is not running SSL http://pastebin.com/jxEjAt1h